# Is the evaporation (liquid to gas conversion) of ethanol dependent on how full you fill it up in a sealed bottle?

Tags: equilibrium, vapor-pressure

It seems intuitive to think that in a bottle (which is air-tight), if you fill up ethanol (or any other volatile liquid) to very full extent, thereby leaving very little headspace, the amount of ethanol evaporated would be reduced. In contrast, if there is more headspace, then more room is allowed for ethanol vapor and hence evaporation would increase. This can also be explained in terms of the smaller increase in partial pressure of ethanol vapor per molecule evaporated with a larger headspace, thereby allowing more time before the forward (evaporation) and backward (condensation) reaction reaches equilibrium.

I would like to know if I'm on track and if not, what did I miss? I do not have the right materials to test it myself and obviously this would not be sophisticated enough to be properly studied in a scientific research (hence I cannot find a specific reference).

Comment: It's **sealed**, i.e. after sufficient time, in equilibrium. The rates are the same.

Comment: Yes, you’ve got the right idea.